# No idea why there are so many -1 in this JS function

Tags: javascript

I want to know what ' A != B ? true : false' stands for. Also, why are so many -1's in this sentence?

```
getBrowser: function() {
    if (null == this.browserName) {
        var a = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        f("[getBrowser()] navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() -> " + a); - 1 != a.indexOf("msie") && -1 == a.indexOf("opera") ? this.browserName2 = this.browserName = "MSIE" : -1 != a.indexOf("iphone") ? (this.browserName = "Netscape Family", this.browserName2 = "iPhone") : -1 != a.indexOf("firefox") && -1 == a.indexOf("opera") ? (this.browserName = "Netscape Family", this.browserName2 = "Firefox") : -1 != a.indexOf("chrome") ? (this.browserName = "Netscape Family", this.browserName2 = "Chrome") : -1 != a.indexOf("safari") ? (this.browserName = "Netscape Family", this.browserName2 = "Safari") : -1 != a.indexOf("mozilla") && -1 == a.indexOf("opera") ? (this.browserName = "Netscape Family", this.browserName2 = "Other") : -1 != a.indexOf("opera") ? (this.browserName = "Netscape Family", this.browserName2 = "Opera") : (this.browserName = "?", this.browserName2 = "unknown");
        f("[getBrowser()] Detected browser name:" + this.browserName + ", " + this.browserName2)
    }
    return this.browserName
},
```

Comment: _"The `indexOf()` method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at `fromIndex`. **Returns -1 if the value is not found**."_ ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf))

Comment: Where do you see `A != B ? true : false` in the code?

Comment: FYI, this is horrible code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, `?` and `:` are used to represent the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), which is actually an `if/else` statement, but written in another form. 
So, this:

```
if (condition) {
    stuff_if_true();
} else {
    stuff_if_false();
}
```

is equivalent with this:

```
condition ?
    stuff_if_true() :
    stuff_if_false()
```

How the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) says, "*The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.*" So, in the code you provided there are just some nested if/else statements written with the ternary operator. They are actually testing the existence of some substrings (chrome, opera etc.) in the `a` variable.

Converted to if/else, the code would be:

```
if (a.indexOf("msie") !== -1 && -1 === a.indexOf("opera")) {
    this.browserName2 = this.browserName = "MSIE"
} else if (-1 !== a.indexOf("iphone")) {
    this.browserName = "Netscape Family";
    this.browserName2 = "iPhone";
} else if (-1 !== a.indexOf("firefox") && -1 === a.indexOf("opera")) {
    this.browserName = "Netscape Family";
    this.browserName2 = "Firefox";
} else if (-1 !== a.indexOf("chrome")) {
    this.browserName = "Netscape Family";
    this.browserName2 = "Chrome";
} else if (-1 !== a.indexOf("safari")) {
    this.browserName = "Netscape Family";
    this.browserName2 = "Safari";
} else if (-1 !== a.indexOf("mozilla") && -1 === a.indexOf("opera")) {
    this.browserName = "Netscape Family";
    this.browserName2 = "Other";
} else if (-1 !== a.indexOf("opera")) {
    this.browserName = "Netscape Family";
    this.browserName2 = "Opera";
} else {
    this.browserName = "?";
    this.browserName2 = "unknown";
    f("[getBrowser()] Detected browser name:" + this.browserName + ", " + this.browserName2)
}
```

You might be confused also because most of the time, you'd see the statemens as `a.indexOf("iphone") !== -1` instead of `-1 !== a.indexOf("iphone")` (they are just switched, but here it means the same thing).

Cheers!

Comment: It's customary to just write `else if` without adding another level of nesting. It makes it easier to see that all the alternatives are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Barmar I used an online tool to conver the code and that was the generated result. I modified the code into if/else if statements and it looks more clean now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, much nicer. You might also want to change the assignments to separate statements, rather than comma expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much! You give me the perfect answer!

Comment: @D-NAO0 you might mark my answer as accepted if you want :) Cheers!
https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer